# OAuth Bug in Apps Script using YouTube Data API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I have used Apps Script successfully on many occasions, and one of the reasons I like it, especially for personal enhancements or projects related to Google Services is just how seamlessly it integrates auth.  However, when trying to integrate the YouTube Data API into one of my Google Sheets' Apps Scripts (I am trying to use the sheet to manage a YouTube playlist), I encountered an error that I have never encountered before.

The code is very simple, I am just trying to get some data from a playlist to return to the logger in the context of my Google Sheets Apps Script.   Note that this Apps Script belongs to the **same account** as the YouTube playlist.  The OAuth Client Verification [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification) specifically state:

> Note: Verification is not required for Apps Script projects whose
> owner and users belong to the same Google Workspace domain or
> customer.

However, when I run my script, the OAuth screen says the app is unverified (this has never happened when I have used any other APIs accessing my own account in Apps Script), and even though I authenticate and it says "Authentication Successful", the script is blocked and it repeatedly (as in forever, in an endless loop) asks me to authenticate again.

Completely at a loss for what is going on.  1.) I shouldn't have to verify this script per the docs I referenced above, and I have never had to before for accessing my own content.  2.) The successful authentication but then failing and repeatedly asking me to authenticate again is driving me mad.

Please advise!

Code is very simple, just trying to get this to return ANYTHING:

```
const syncVideos = () => {
  let response = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet,contentDetails', {'playlistId': '<REDACTED>'});
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: And yes, I have enabled the YouTube Data API in Advanced Services.

Comment: Calling the function you posted gives me `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.playlistItems.list failed with error: 'statistics' `, but it works fine if I remove  'statistics' from the first parameter of list(). And indeed 'statistics' is not included as a name of the part parameter: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#parameters.

Comment: It's true that 'statistics' is not apparently a 'part' available through the PlaylistItems.list API endpoint... but this has no bearing on the actual issue at hand, and removing 'statistics' here does nothing to solve the issue I am experiencing.

Comment: Please post the entire context of code issuing the OAuth authentication/authorization flow, of course editing out any credentials data (that is private data).

Comment: Note: The same thing happens if I use urlfetch:

```javascript
const syncVideos = () => {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&playlistId=<REDACTED>", {
    headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` },
  });
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: @stvar the OAuth flow happens automatically when you run apps script requesting personal data.   There is no other code. The same thing happens when I try to run Google's sample code for YouTube Data API as well.  The whole point of using Apps Script entirely was to not have to build any auth functionality.

Comment: @Avana: of course same thing happens with `UrlFetchApp`. This is not an issue of the API call itself, but of OAuth flow.

Comment: @stvar yes, that's my point.   There's nothing wrong with the code, so what's going wrong with OAuth?   It's supposed to be handled natively within Apps Script, when Google APIs are speaking to one another.

Furthermore, it says authorization successful... before asking me to authenticate again and again and again.

Comment: @Avana: Could you successfully proceed going through the steps specified by YouTube's official [Apps Script Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/apps-script)?

Comment: @stvar I have done that, this is what I was referring to when I wrote "The same thing happens when I try to run Google's sample code for YouTube Data API".   Same result after following those steps exactly.

Comment: @Avana: As you may already know, the OAuth authentication/authorization works this way (irrespective of the kind of programming environment that surrounds the API calls): (step 1) have a successful OAuth flow (that is the user granting permissions to the app) that provides back a (long-lived) refresh token and a (short-lived) access token; then issue the API call passing on that access token; (step N) issue an API call without OAuth flow, using the *stored* refresh token by passing to the API the (eventually freshened up) access token.

Comment: @Avana: For some reason (yet to be found), you're stuck at *step 1*, never succeeding to proceed to *step N*. The question to be answered (this requires some digging into the Apps Script workings w.r.t. OAuth): why is that your script *is not storing somehow* the refresh token obtained, for to use that further the next time calling an API endpoint?

Comment: @stvar see this [screen recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ddwqybulpyzlx1/recording.mp4?dl=0) re: apps script quickstart

Comment: @Avana: Yes, I see.

Comment: @stvar I'll be damned.  It works when I use my "main channel" but I can't seem to use Apps Script to query my other channel, my son's channel which is set up for kids.  Weirdly I have no problems accessing either when using the API Explorer to do API calls.   Even though I log in with my son's channel, it doesn't work.

Unfortunately I am doing this to automatically manage the channel I set up for my son on my YouTube account, not my 'main channel'.

Comment: @Avana: Please note that OAuth authentication/authorization works on a per YouTube channel basis. Two different channels implies two different (that is: separate) OAuth flows where you (the user) authenticate separately to each channel and authorize twice the (maybe the same) app.

Comment: @stvar The embarrassing resolution to this all is that I apparently only had to log into my MAIN channel to access my other channels, which IMO is counterintuitive since I was trying to query my other channels.    But this is solved.  Not sure if this will even be helpful for others, maybe I should just delete it.

Comment: @Avana: (In general, it's not a good idea to delete questions posted for various reason, e.g. there could be users that deem your findings helpful.) Now, you said in the question's text that *am trying to use the sheet to manage a YouTube playlist.* If *managing* implies only reading public info (not reading private data, not inserting/modifying/deleting public or private data), then an API key suffices (no OAuth flow at all). An API key could make your things a bit easier, modulo the *only-reading public data* condition.

Comment: @Avana: Also a valid OAuth authorization on channel say `A` enables you to read public data pertaining to any channel `B` (with `B` different than `A`).

Comment: @stvar I tried to move this to chat but it won't let me.   The data that I was accessing is private.   I personally find it very strange that it even asks you to sign into a specific channel, if in fact only signing into the "original" channel will result in a valid OAuth.

Also still unresolved is the fact that the documentation says:

`Note: Verification is not required for Apps Script projects whose owner and users belong to the same Google Workspace domain or customer.`

, but the OAuth screen still says that the app is unverified and makes me step through the whole 'advanced' thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** This turned out to not be a code or OAuth issue really, but more of an unintuitive procedure when authenticating, i.e. when authenticating with Google to access one of your channel's data through the YouTube Data API, authenticate with your main channel, even if requesting data from other channels connected to your account.